# How would i resize a PreView component in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, resize, preview

As i'm new to Kotlin and android development i have no code to show except the code for previewing my camera. I have no idea how to achive my goal to simply resize my preview screen with a touch of a button.

Comment: The same way you resize any View, which is to modify its LayoutParams. You can find other questions with answers on that subject here.

Comment: This [Link](https://tomoima525.medium.com/how-to-programmatically-control-preview-size-of-android-camera-app-62c26168b784) might help.